# CakePHP keeps connection open for exactly 5 seconds

Tags: php, cakephp, web-hosting

I've just finished a CakePHP website which works like a charm in local. So, I put it online.
The problem is that , although pages are generated pretty quickly (around 400ms), my browser shows the loading symbol for 5 long seconds.

My Firefox dev console shows that the browser is in "receiving" state for EXACTLY 5 seconds, every time. Actually, the page is displayed way before, but it seems that for some reason the connection stays open for precisely 5 seconds.

It's actually boring because, let alone the loading sign that appears even though the page is fully loaded and usable, AJAX calls will last 5 seconds too. So AJAX content can't be displayed before 5s, which is obviously unacceptable for users.

I've tested the problem on several computers, browsers, and internet connections. I've also tested a vanilla CakePHP on the same host, and encountered the same problem.

So do you have any idea of which host setting could cause that? I believe that this only can happen because the server is keeping the connection open, not because the client is. But i can't figure out the reason. I hope you will !

Comment: Here is a screenshot : http://oi62.tinypic.com/357qe86.jpg
Sorry, I have a french browser. 

Anyway, you can see that I have no 404s. On the right, "Attente" means waiting and "Réception" means receiving. So the index.php is actually being received for 5 seconds whereas it was displayed a long time ago.

Comment: In that case check your page source (use curl, it's easier to see) to see what comes after a delay.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. But since a vanilla CakePHP doesn't change the problem, any source code issue will only be part of the solution, won't it?

Comment: You need to identify a problem first - since there's no code in the question I've no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Strangely, cURL returns nothing on CAKEPHP pages, and no curl_errno displays no error. 
However, it can display every pages which are not generated by CakePHP.
I removed url rewriting but it doesn't change much.

Comment: As you can see on this screenshot : http://oi60.tinypic.com/66w0lf.jpg, firefox is able to display the page, but curl with the exact same url returns *nothing*.
What i know is that plain PHP pages work just fine, but CakePHP + this host act so weird...

Comment: why are you curling a different url than you're using in the browser? Please use an appropriate medium for your question - e.g. the cake irc chat, comments aren't appropriate for discussion. You should look at the headers in your curl response, it's probably a redirect but also compare like with like - you're currently using different urls - good luck (i.e. no more comments =)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problème.
It's not the good solution, but you can force the php  script to close http connection at the end of Ajax action :

```
function AjaxEdit(){
    // do some thing
    header( "Connection: Close" );
}
```